# ListView.CheckBoxes property not shown in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview

I'm totally new in programming so sorry for dumb question. I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 .NET Framework 4.0. I've created listView element and I want to add checkboxes to the each item inside. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I've read that there is a property called CheckBoxes and all what I've to do is to change it to "true". But my problem is that I don't have this property. I added

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

but it didn't help. I feel like I'm doing wrong. Help me please.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but are you sure you clicked on the listview? You are missing several of the properties.

Comment: They are sorted alphabetical and on scroll down there are a lot more properties. And yes listView1 is checked... =\

Comment: Do you have selected the ListView in the designer? Looks you've selected something else..

Comment: Can you access the property through code? i.e. listView1.CheckBoxes. Does intellisense show up?

Comment: Please check updated screenshot. I've an error that CheckBoxes property not found for ListView when I try to access it throught the code. But I may be wrong with that cause I'm not really clear where to paste the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot, you're developing WPF application, but [`CheckBoxes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx) property is related to Windows Forms `ListView`.

If you want your items to be checked in WPF `ListView`, you should add a column with appropriate data template:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: OMG.. Thank you, I didn't thought about it. My bad.